# Firebug Losing Marbles

Tags: javascript, firebug

I've noticed recently firebug is starting to throw javascript errors about code that it hasn't before. Such as `$ is not defined` and also errors with Jquery and processingjs core, which i'm assuming is error free.

Anyone else getting this, and should I just ignore it?

Comment: Firebug sometimes has problems interacting with other Firefox plugins. Have you installed any other plugins recently?

Comment: Nothing within the last month. I'm also getting a problem with Apache stopping working on a codeigniter site on localhost. Maybe the js code in the head isn't loading properly. Might not be firebug after all, it's usually pretty reliable. I'll have to check it on some other sites.

Comment: I assume you have restarted firefox completely? Sometimes firebug gets funky on me, and all I have to do is close all FF windows and make sure the process terminates (to make sure you get a fresh start) and kick it on again

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> should I just ignore it?

Probably not: Errors in reference libraries like jQuery often stem from their functions being called with incorrect parameters.

It's impossible to say more without details, but it is definitely worth investigating why this happens.

Comment: +1.  Not to mention plugins can internally call jQuery functions, and if called incorrectly, the error will show as originating from jQuery, not the plugin.

Comment: Thanks @Pekka good answer, I didn't know that. It's probably just be down to my js.